# Number of length-n ordered lists consisting of integers b/w 0 and k-1 whose entries sum to a multiple of k is k^{n-1}

Tags: probability, combinatorics

As stated in the title, I am trying to understand why the number of length-n ordered lists consisting of integers between 0 and k-1 whose entries sum to a multiple of k is $k^{n-1}$. Here, $k$ is any positive integer and $n \geq 1$.

I tried k = 3 and n = 2. Indeed, there are 3 sequences that satisfy the condition, namely: (2, 1), (0, 0), (1, 2). I am pretty sure that the Inclusion/Exclusion principle would provide an easy way to wrap my head around why the statement is true in general, but I'm not quite sure how to apply the formula here. Any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You don’t need inclusion-exclusion. There are $k$ integers between $0$ and $k-1$ inclusive, so there are $k^{n-1}$ ordered lists of length $n-1$ that can be formed from them. Once such a list is formed, there is exactly one number in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$ that can be appended to the list to make a list of length $n$ whose sum is divisible by $k$; think in terms of congruence modulo $k$.

Answer (score 0):

We get from first principles the generating function

$$f(z) = (1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{k-1})^n$$

Now let $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i/k).$

The desired quantity is given by

$$\frac{1}{k} \sum_{q=0}^{k-1} f(\zeta^q) =
\frac{1}{k}
\left(k^n +
\sum_{q=1}^{k-1}
\frac{(1-\zeta^{qk})^n}{(1-\zeta^q)^n}\right).$$

All the sum terms are zero, however, because $\zeta^{qk} = 1.$
That leaves just $k^n/k = k^{n-1}$ as claimed. This is because
$\sum_{q=0}^{k-1} \zeta^{qp}$ is $k$ when $p$ is a multiple of $k$
and $(1-\zeta^{pk})/(1-\zeta^p) = 0$ otherwise.